# If $f^3$ measurable, show $f$ is measurable (Check my solution please)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, borel-sets

I am new on this site. I am wondering if my solution is correct.

I know we can do this using the fact that composition of continuous functions with a measurable one is measurable, but I want to see if my reasoning is correct for this specific example. 
Let X be a set, with sigma algebra $A$.
Suppose $f: X\to \mathbb{R}$, and suppose $f^3$ is measurable. Then show that $f$ is measurable.

My attempt: Let $a \in \mathbb{R}$, we will show $\{x: f(x)<a\}$ is measurable. Now $\{x: f(x)<a\}=\{x: f^3(x)<a^3\}$. But $\{x: f^3(x)<a^3\}$ is measurable as $f^3$ is measurable. Hence since $a$ is arbitrary and the intervals $(-\infty,b)$ generate the borel sigma algebra, $f$ is measurable.

Thanks in advance.

And if its not correct, please tell me why.

Edit: The sigma algebra on R is assumed to be the Borel sigma algebra.

Comment: This is correct

Comment: Thanks, could anyone else confirm too?

Comment: Note that you've used the injectivity of $x \mapsto x^3$ here. What if you were trying to prove that $f^2$ measurable implies $f$ measurable? How would you do it?

Comment: Then I would need something more right?  I would need to know what kind of function f is?

Comment: Yeah, actually it's not true because you could just let $f$ be $-1$ on some non-measurable set and $1$ everywhere else

Comment: Yes thank you. I feel like something is wrong with my proof though somehow?

Comment: There is definitely nothing wrong with your proof. It's a very simple problem -- you got it!

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation!